# Why with Webdriverio the action Double Click doesn't work

Tags: selenium, double-click, webdriver-io

When calling `doubleClick()` as shown in the code below,it only makes one click at the level of the chosen selector but not double clicking it.However, double click is one of the webdriverio API, i didn't understand why doubleclick does not work.
I used selenium as a server, and chrome as a browser.

```
waitForVisibleAndDoubleClick(selector, pause = 0, timeout = 90000) {
    return this.client
      .pause(pause)
      .moveToObject(selector)
      .waitForVisibleAndDoubleClick(selector,timeout);
  }
client.addCommand('waitForVisibleAndDoubleClick', function (selector, timeout = 90000) {
    return client
      .waitForVisible(selector, timeout)
      .doubleClick(selector);
  });
```

Comment: How are you concluding _...only make one click at the level of the chosen selector but not double click..._?

Comment: I concluded when I tested it and I see it

Comment: Is there any UI action after one click on element?

Comment: No.I just want to use the doubleclick action instead of using the click action twice

Comment: Maybe your selector matches with more than one element?

Comment: No, it's a checkbox

Comment: @MimiSoftware Why on earth would you _doubleclick_ a _checkbox_ instead of a _click_?

Comment: A double click is nothing special... it IS just a single click action done twice in close succession.

Comment: I think that, doubleClick() works fine but it clicking very fast and don't makes any actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code please, use `doDoubleClick()` instead of `doubleClick()` , Differences between them is doDoubleClick() is performing actions on mouse's current position :

```
waitForVisibleAndDoubleClick(selector, pause = 0, timeout = 90000) {
    return this.client
      .pause(pause)
      .moveToObject(selector)
      .waitForVisibleAndDoubleClick(selector,timeout);
  }
client.addCommand('waitForVisibleAndDoubleClick', function (selector, timeout = 90000) {
    return client
      .waitForVisible(selector, timeout)
      .doDoubleClick(selector);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This following steps worked for me with Webdriverio+Nodejs:

```
    await return driver.click(locator);
    await driver.doDoubleClick();
```

The description for doDoubleClick states "*Double-clicks at the current mouse coordinates*". So, In the first click(), provide the locator to the object you want to doubleClick.